# Solve equations for all values of variables, rejecting certain types of solution

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I have an expression, `expr`, containing 3 variables, 4 coefficients and 2 non-zero generic constants. I want to solve for the 4 coefficients such that the equation holds for all values of the variables and for all non-zero values of the constants. It is possible to solve either `expr == 0` or `expr == 1`.  Acceptable solutions should not assign a specific value to the constants. Also, I do not want solutions that set all 4 coefficients simultaneously to zero.

Example:

Let `x`,`y`,`z` be the variables, `a1`,`a2`,`a3`,`a4` be the coefficients and `b1`,`b2` be the generic non-zero constants.

```
expr =
  -2*a3*b1 + a1*x + a2*x + a3*x + a4*x + (a3*b1*y)/b2 - (a4*b1*y)/b2 + 
   2*a1*z - 2*a1*b2*z - 4*a2*b2*z - 2*a3*b2*z - 2*a4*b2*z;

SolveAlways[{b1 != 0, b2 != 0, expr == 0}, {x, y, z}]
(* {{a2 -> -a1, a4 -> 0, a3 -> 0, b2 -> -1}, {a2 -> 0, a4 -> 0, a1 -> 0, 
  a3 -> 0}} *)

SolveAlways[{b1 != 0, b2 != 0, expr == 1}, {x, y, z}]
(* {{a2 -> -((2 a3)/(1 + b2)), a4 -> a3, a1 -> -((2 a3 b2)/(1 + b2)), 
  b1 -> -(1/(2 a3))}} *)
```

Here I would want to automatically select only the last solution, all the others do not meet my criteria. Also, it should be rearranged so as to assign a value to `a3` dependent on `b1`, not the other way around.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding getting `a`s in terms of `b`s and not vice versa: just treat the output as another system of equations:

```
In[2]:= SolveAlways[{b1 != 0, b2 != 0, expr == 1}, {x, y, z}]
Out[2]= {{a2 -> -((2 a3)/(1 + b2)), a4 -> a3, a1 -> -((2 a3 b2)/(1 + b2)), b1 -> -(1/(2 a3))}}

In[3]:= Equal @@@ First[%]
Out[3]= {a2 == -((2 a3)/(1 + b2)), a4 == a3, a1 == -((2 a3 b2)/(1 + b2)), b1 == -(1/(2 a3))}

In[4]:= Solve[%, {a1, a2, a3, a4}]
Out[4]= {{a1 -> b2/(b1 (1 + b2)), a2 -> 1/(b1 (1 + b2)), a3 -> -(1/(2 b1)), a4 -> -(1/(2 b1))}}
```

The trivial `a1==a2==a3==a4==0` solution can be filtered using [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteCases.html) after you have [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sort.html)ed each solution to put the `a`s in order and therefore directly comparable with `{a1 -> 0, a2 -> 0, a3 -> 0, a4 -> 0}`.

Comment: This nearly answers my question, perhaps I can use DeleteCases also to remove unwanted solutions that assign values to `b1` and `b2`.

Comment: The following seems to do the trick:     `DeleteCases[DeleteCases[Solve[#, {a1, a2, a3, a4}] & @@ {Apply[Equal, #, {1}]} & /@ 
    SolveAlways[{b1 != 0, b2 != 0, expr == 0}, {x, y, z}], {{a1 -> 0, 
     a2 -> 0, a3 -> 0, a4 -> 0}}], {}]`. Not exactly pretty. I'm not sure it will always eliminate solutions that assign values to `b1` and `b2`. It does in this particular case. It also produces quite deeply nested lists, presumably because both `Solve` and `SolveAlways` produce lists of lists.

Comment: Sorry, above should read: `Sort @@ DeleteCases[Solve[#, {a1, a2, a3, a4}] & @@ {Apply[Equal, #, {1}]} & /@ 
    SolveAlways[{b1 != 0, b2 != 0, expr == 0}, {x, y, z}], {{a1 -> 0, 
     a2 -> 0, a3 -> 0, a4 -> 0}}]`. Forgot to `Sort` which also seems to remove empty lists from lists.